# How do I replace an instruction with a value?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm writing in C++. Say I have

```
define void @ha(i32) #0 {
  %2 = add nsw i32 %0, 1
  %3 = sub nsw i32 %2, 1
  ret void
}
```

I'd like to replace

```
%3 = sub nsw i32 %2, 1
```

with

```
%3 = %0
```

I've tried

```
inst_iter->replaceAllUsesWith(val);
inst_iter->eraseFromParent();
```

and
    ReplaceInstWithValue(inst_iter->getParent()->getInstList(), inst_iter, val);

The first understandably does not work, as it does not have another reference; for the second one, it just deletes the instruction. I couldn't find an appropriate function either (and I haven't included IRBuilder). Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want is [replaceAllUsesWith()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a3ab5fc45117b450e8bb04e564cb6e5f2). Find your `sub` and replace all uses of that instruction with. Done.

Comment: looks like my test case code was too short so it just optimized the entire line out, thank you for this comment!